# Format issue in SQL output

Tags: sql

I am facing a problem in formatting the output of a query:

```
  SELECT i.product AS "Product Line",
  COUNT(i.incident_id) "Count Of Tickets",
  TRUNC((SUM(NVL(RSSEC,0) - NVL(WCTSEC,0))/COUNT(i.incident_id)) / 86400)
  || ':'
  || TRUNC(MOD(((SUM(NVL(RSSEC,0) - NVL(WCTSEC,0))/COUNT(i.incident_id)) / 3600),24))
  || ':'
  || TRUNC(MOD(((SUM(NVL(RSSEC,0) - NVL(WCTSEC,0))/COUNT(i.incident_id)) / 60),60))
  || ':'
  || TRUNC(MOD((SUM( NVL(RSSEC,0) - NVL(WCTSEC,0))/COUNT(i.incident_id)),60)) AS "MTTR"
FROM info i;
```

where 
RSSEC-Total RSeconds(type number)
WCTSEC- Total WSeconds(type number)

```
Current Output:
TTPLL       8   2:4:0:18
ASDASDADD   1   0:0:9:0
UASDF       2   0:0:0:8
ERTEU       4   0:3:0:46
```

```
Expected Output:
TTPLL       8   02:04:00:18
ASDASDADD   1   00:00:09:00
UASDF       2   00:00:00:08
ERTEU       4   00:03:00:46
```

Can anyone help me out to achieve the above format?

Please let me know for any alternative solution to get above output format other than truncate position.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What database vendor (Oracle, MS SQL Server, mySQL) are you using?  Have you looked at their SQL documentation for format functions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which RDBMS this is, so I'm guessing, but how about this one?

```
  SELECT i.product AS "Product Line",
  COUNT(i.incident_id) "Count Of Tickets",
  RIGHT('0' || TRUNC((SUM(NVL(RSSEC,0) - NVL(WCTSEC,0))/COUNT(i.incident_id)) / 86400), 2)
  || ':'
  || RIGHT('0' || TRUNC(MOD(((SUM(NVL(RSSEC,0) - NVL(WCTSEC,0))/COUNT(i.incident_id)) / 3600),24)), 2)
  || ':'
  || RIGHT('0' || TRUNC(MOD(((SUM(NVL(RSSEC,0) - NVL(WCTSEC,0))/COUNT(i.incident_id)) / 60),60)), 2)
  || ':'
  || RIGHT('0' || TRUNC(MOD((SUM( NVL(RSSEC,0) - NVL(WCTSEC,0))/COUNT(i.incident_id)),60)), 2) AS "MTTR"
FROM info i;
```